# PHP/SQL can't use data from query after while loop

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user='$user'" ); 

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $data['user']; //this is fine

}

echo $data['user'];
$data=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $data['user'];
```

The last two echos are empty?

I need to have an array outside of the loop that is equivalent to the 'last' loop cycle.

Comment: the last 2 echos are empty : this is because .. the variable definition of $data only belongs to wihle loop. and outside it the loop it won't be accessible. its a general concept

Comment: on the second example I redeclare $data

Comment: Um... I don't see a second example?

Comment: @NullPoiиteяღ PHP doesn't use block scoping, it uses function and class scoping.

Comment: The last `mysql_fetch_array()` returns `false` because there are no more rows to fetch -- the loop fetched everything.

Comment: ok so what's the solution though, other than repeating the query.

Comment: @user1209203, that depends on what you want to do with the data after the loop.

Comment: @Barmar thanks i  missed it after migrating c from php .. i apologize  user1209203 for my comment

Comment: I just want to echo it, but not in the loop as that produces to many echos, I want to be able to access an array of the last loop effectively.

Comment: Set a variable inside the loop.

Comment: If you only want the value from one row, why don't you change your query to use `LIMIT 1`? Then you don't need a loop.

Comment: there is actually more than one result in practice

Comment: this is just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop keeps fetching data, until there is no more data and therefore `false` is returned by `mysql_fetch_array`. This last value, `false`, is still in `$data` after the loop has ended, but simply printing it using `echo`, won't print anything you can see. The same goes for the next call of `mysql_fetch_array` and `echo`. You can check this by doing a `var_dump` of the `$data` variable. This will show you that it contains the boolean `false`.

If you want to be able to use the data after the loop has ended, you can save all the data you fetch into one big array. That might be a bad option though if you're fetching a lot of data, but from there you should be able to change it yourself so you can save and use the useful data. To store all the data in an array, change the loop into this:

```
$alldata = array();
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  echo $data['user'];
  $alldata[] = $data;
}
```

You can then for example iterate over `$alldata` to go over the results again.

**Update**: In your last comment you said you want to access the last record that was fetched. You can do that like this:

```
$lastdata = array();
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  echo $data['user'];
  $lastdata = $data;
}
```

`$lastdata` will then contain the last record in your result.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the following:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    // mysql_fetch_array returned something 'not false' and this value
    // is assigned to $daat
}
// mysql_fetch_array() returned false, because there are no more rows
// false is assigned to $data, and because the statement within while(...)
// isn't true anymore the loop is stopped.
```

Use

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
if (!$data) {
    echo "User don't exists";
}
```

for example to handle this situation